# Cómo usar subconsulta en una consulta MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Agradecería su apoyo con esta duda respecto a una consulta en `MySql` que todo gira entorno a una única tabla.

la tabla se llama **empleado_motivo** y cuenta con los datos de **id**, **nombre_empleado**, **incidencia_int**

Donde quedarían los registros de la siguiente manera:

| id | nombre | incidencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jose | 1 |
| 2 | jose | 0 |
| 3 | jose | 2 |
| 4 | pedro | 1 |
| 5 | laura | 1 |
| 6 | laura | 1 |

Y haciendo un `count` muestro el numero de incidencias por cada nombre registrado.

```
SELECT  nombre AS Nombre_Empleado, COUNT(nombre) AS Cantidad_incidencias 
FROM Empleado;
```

| Nombre_Empleado | Cantidad_incidencias |
| --- | --- |
| jose | 3 |
| pedro | 1 |
| laura | 2 |

Requiero que apareciera de la siguiente forma pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

| Nombre_Empleado | Cantidad_incidencias | Descripcion_Incidencias |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jose | 3 | 1,0,2 |
| pedro | 1 | 2,1 |
| laura | 2 | 1 |

En el campo **Descripcion_Incidencias** se tendrían que listar las descripciones del campo **incidencia**.

Agradecería su apoyo.

Comment: Que es **descripcion_incidencias**?

Comment: De donde están viniendo los datos de Descripcion_Incindencias

Si es una tabla podrías efectuar in INNER JOIN tomando como referencia su ID, pero para poder ayudarte debes colocar el contexto de tu problema completo

Comment: @jesus_san1 ahi se deberían de agrupar los diferentes tipos de movimientos

Comment: @LuisJairJuarezSanchez el problema es que no hay una tabla de catálogo de incidencias, vienen en un procedimiento al insertar los datos, es por parte de un desarrollo viejo oor decirlo así y funcionó en su momento pero ahora piden un histórico de esq información

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con **GROUP_CONCAT** de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT nombre AS Nombre_Empleado, 
COUNT(nombre) AS Cantidad_incidencias, 
GROUP_CONCAT(incidencia) AS Incidencias 
FROM empleado_motivo 
WHERE nombre IS NOT NULL 
group by nombre ORDER BY Cantidad_incidencias DESC;
```

Resultado:

| Nombre_Empleado | Cantidad_incidencias | Incidencias |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jose | 3 | 1,0,2 |
| laura | 2 | 1,1 |
| pedro | 1 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Dime si te sirvio.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, me sirve de mucho ya que es una base que no tiene ninguna relacion, de nuevo gracias,

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar con la siguiente instrucción, no tengo una BD para ejecutar el query, pero puedes tomarlo como base. Inténtalo y me cuentas

```
SELECT nombre AS Nombre_Empleado, 
GROUP_CONCAT(incidencia SEPARATOR ', ') AS Descripcion_Incidencias, 
COUNT(nombre) AS Cantidad_incidencias 
FROM Empleado GROUP BY nombre;
```

Comment: Existen herramientas para hacer pruebas online, tales como http://sqlfiddle.com/ y https://www.db-fiddle.com/